# probability density function (PDF)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a function defined as:
**P_{n}=p+ (n-1)beta**.   where n={1,2, ....} and 0<=p<=1.
which condition can I impose on **beta** for this function to be a probability density function (PDF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible in the way you have stated your problem: A PDF needs to represent a probability distribution, i.e. you need to impose that the sum of all the probabilities is exactly $1$.

In this case, you would have $1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (p + (n-1) \beta)$ which diverges no matter the value of $\beta$ (I assume beta is constant).
Even with $p=0$, you would end up with the Harmonic series, which is also divergent.

If you make $\beta = \beta(n)$ not constant, then you would need to have something which gets rid of $p$ and then imposes a convergent series (something like $1/n^2$ for instance).

Cheers